# How to use build arg to pass PUBLIC_API_URL while deploying NextJS web application using google cloud run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, next.js, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I added PUBLIC_API_URL on my dockerfile and also on Environment variable on cloud run while setting up the service. But the PUBLIC_API_URL passed on build is not passing and the api url is missing in the running application.

Any idea how to accomplish this task? I'll provide any additional info if needed.

Comment: Please share Dockerfile e command you use to run.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.